# Where are the sensors of the EMF/RF meter on the circuit board?

Tags: radiation, emf, meter

[image]

In the attached photo you can see the PCB of a simple EMF/RF meter.

This meter shows, at the same time, the values of the electric field,
magnetic field, and power density (see small illustration on the right/bottom of the photo).

Where are the sensors (magnetic field sensor, electric field sensor, and RF radiation sensor) located on that circuit board?

Comment: The spiral trace on the edge is one of them. L8 in the corner is probably another.

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - this basically means that if you want to know about how a certain piece of bought electronics operates, you need to provide full technical details so this can be explained. Of course, if you had full tech details then you'd figure this out yourself so, basically, it boils down to your question being unsuitable.

Comment: @brhans,what does the spiral trace sensor senses,magnetic or electric field?and refer to L8,did you intended to L2(up right corner)?

Comment: @Andy aka,I made a search in all the stack exchange sites options and i didn't find more suitable site to ask this question.Which forum can i ask this question?I am curious to know how each sensor looks like in that pcb.

Comment: Stack exchange isn't a forum; it's a Q and A site.

Comment: Yes the one in the top-right corner - it looked like an 8 at first glance.

Comment: @brhans,can you tell what does each one detect(electric/magnetic fields or rf radiation)?

Comment: @Andy aka,may you recommend a better Q and A site among all the other stack exchange sites?I don't see a better option.

Comment: No, sorry, I may not.

Comment: @Andy aka,i meant an appropriate site for that type of question.I didn't mean a better site than this one.

Comment: My answer is still the same.

Comment: Magnetic field is probably one of the small ICs. brhans answered the other two.

Comment: Okay,one of the small ICs is probably the magnetic field sensor.Which one between the other options is the RF sensor?(the one that detects power density EM radiation),the spiral trace or the L2 coil?